# Ajax in Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

So, I was playing around with Angular Js and Async calls in a bid to move away from $JQuery, but I have run into some strange issue while performing the ajax calls.

So, in order to follow 'best practices', I moved my ajax requests to a service, and then perform the ajax calls in my controllers using my service created.

The issue I'm running into is that the ajax requests does not hit my server when perfoming the call using the service.

Here is an image of the simplified service I defined.

[image]

Here is an image of the simplified controller I am using.

[image]

On the other hand, when I execute the ajax call directly from the controller, it hits the server. Anyone know why this is happening ?

Comment: Missing semicolon ?

Comment: please post your actual code, **not** images of it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not making a call, you have:

```
ajaxService.GetAllEmployees.then
```

while you should have

```
ajaxService.GetAllEmployees().then( ... )
```

Missing `()`

Comment: @user3295929 happy that helps :)